# Linear independence of a set of states, and the non-vanishing determinant of the matrix comprised of their inner products

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

So I have a very basic question in linear algebra, but I'll phrase it in terms of QM.

Suppose we are given a set of $N$ states $\{ | \psi_i \rangle\}$. Construct the $N \times N$ matrix

$$\mathcal{M}_{ij} \equiv \langle \psi_i | \psi_j \rangle,$$

and suppose $\det \mathcal{M} \neq 0$. This implies that the set of $N$ column vectors $\{ | \phi_i \rangle\}$, given by

$$
| \phi_i \rangle =
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle \psi_1 | \psi_i \rangle \\
\langle \psi_2 | \psi_i \rangle \\
\vdots \\
\langle \psi_N | \psi_i \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$$

are linearly independent. Does this also imply linear independence of the set $\{ | \psi_i \rangle\}$? If yes, why?

Comment: Yes. Take a 3x3 case and convince yourself that if the 3 bras were dependent, adding suitable first and 2nd row multiples on the third in $\cal M$ would result in a null third row, so vanishing determinant contrary to your assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the argument you applied to the *N* $\{ |\phi_i\rangle \}$ s this time to the matrix $\cal N$ of the $\{ |\psi_i\rangle \}$ s.

For linear dependence, $\cal N$ *must* have a null eigenvalue, and so should $\cal {N^\dagger N}=\cal{M} $, contrary to assumption.

($\cal N$ is *T×N*, for $N\leq T\leq\infty$, and your *φ* construction ensured you worked in the *N*-subspace of the *T*-Hilbert space.)

The question should be in the math SE.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Indeed, you are right about the misplacement of the question, my apologies.